# Not getting data in Web service through json

Tags: jquery, html, web-services

```
 var questionOptionArray=[{"questionCode":"1111111177","optionCode":"1111111147"},                 {"questionCode":"1111111103","optionCode":"test"},{"questionCode":"1111111104","optionCode":"1111111212"},{"questionCode":"1111111105","optionCode":"1111111215"},{"questionCode":"1111111106","optionCode":"test2"}]
  var jsonobj = JSON.stringify(questionOptionArray);
            alert(jsonobj);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/Quiz.asmx/InsertUserQuiz",
                data: JSON.stringify({ questionOptionArray: questionOptionArray }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) { alert(data); },
                failure: OnError
            });

        }
```

in quiz.asmx my code:

```
public class Quiz : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public class optionDetail
        {
            string questionCode { get; set; }
            string optionCode { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string InsertUserQuiz(List<optionDetail> questionOptionArray)
        {
            var count = questionOptionArray.Count();
            return "1";
        }
    }
```

i am getting null value of questionOptionArray with five count.
,how to get values of questionCode ,optionCode in web service so  that i can
insert them in database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you method expects a list of `optionDetail` try sending it an array of those objects.

```
 var questionOptionArray=[{"questionCode":"1111111177","optionCode":"1111111147"},{"questionCode":"1111111103","optionCode":"test"},{"questionCode":"1111111104","optionCode":"1111111212"},{"questionCode":"1111111105","optionCode":"1111111215"},{"questionCode":"1111111106","optionCode":"test2"}];
  var jsonobj = JSON.stringify(questionOptionArray);
            alert(jsonobj);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/Quiz.asmx/InsertUserQuiz",
                data: jsonobj,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) { alert(data); },
                failure: OnError
            });

        }
```